# python requests: how to check for "200 OK"

Tags: python, python-requests

What is the easiest way to check whether the response received from a requests post was "200 OK" or an error has occurred?

I tried doing something like this:

```
....
resp = requests.post(my_endpoint_var, headers=header_var, data=post_data_var)
print(resp)
if resp == "<Response [200]>":
    print ('OK!')
else:
    print ('Boo!')
```

The output on the screen is:

```
Response [200] (including the "<" and ">")
Boo!
```

So even though I am getting a 200, my check in the if statement is somehow not matching?

Comment: I am not sure if it would work, but try to replace print(resp) with print(resp.status_code) and check if it works

Comment: I think resp should have a field "status_code". Check for resp.status_code == 200

Comment: Your comparison operation fails because you are [comparing objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) of different types: a [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) object on the right *with* a [`requests.models.Response`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/v3.0.0/api/#requests.Response) instance on the left. What you want on the left is the [string representation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) of the response object. That said, the answers to this question present better ways to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/?highlight=status_code#response-status-codes), there's a status_code property on the response-object. So you can do the following:

```py
if resp.status_code == 200:
    print ('OK!')
else:
    print ('Boo!')
```

##### EDIT:

As others have pointed out, a simpler check might be:

```py
if resp.ok:
    print ('OK!')
else:
    print ('Boo!')
```

That is, if you want to consider all `2xx` response codes and not `200` explicitly.
You may also want to check Peter's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58465267/3761628) for a more python-like way to do this.

Comment: It could be worth mentioning, that while the `resp` object *prints as* `<Response [200]>` this not means it is identical to that string.

Comment: The link on 'docs' gives a 404

Answer (score 51):

Just checking the response attribute `resp.ok is True` is sufficient for all 2xx responses (while it will be `False` for 4xx and 5xx)

However, a potentially more Pythonic way to check for success would be to test and optionally raise an exception with [`Response.raise_for_status()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status) (which will raise `requests.HTTPError` if the request was unsuccessful, or continue without interruption for a successful request)

This can be directly handled or raised to the calling function (which might, for example, try the request again after a few seconds if it believes the error was transient)

```py
try:
    resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, timeout=timeout)
    resp.raise_for_status()
except requests.HTTPError as ex:
    # possibly check response for a message
    raise ex  # let the caller handle it
except requests.Timeout:
    # request took too long
```

---

[EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-EAFP): It’s **E**asier to **A**sk for **F**orgiveness than **P**ermission
It's frequently clearer to just do what you expect to work and if an exception is raised from the operation, except and handle it.

Finally, note that some APIs will return a valid response (200) for errors with information about why the request was bad, while others may respond with a 400-level with additional information that might be useful (such as a link to documentation or a specific message about what to do), which can be worth checking for.

Comment: While EAFP works for _most_ of Python, I think in this case it's better asking for the response first. If you're dealing with an API for example, it could give a 4xx response without raising any exception.

Comment: This is the way!

Comment: At first, I thought that the [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108589/peter) who has answered this was the same [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2403000/peter) who raised the [EAFP caveat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087303/python-requests-how-to-check-for-200-ok#comment105694404_58465267) in the comments. That said, there are issues with both comments. See my other comments below.

Comment: I am giving this a downvote, as it does not quite answer the asker's question about "how to ascertain a [HTTP 200 OK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200)". [`resp.ok`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.ok) covers a broader range of values -- status codes below 400 that is. A [simple check for a status code that is equal to 200](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54087354/1650240) achieves the goal.

Comment: [@Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2403000/peter): Exception raising is not a function of the actual [HTTP API or the web service](https://www.educative.io/blog/what-are-rest-apis#http) being interacted with. In this case, it is the result of evaluating the same "response" which you refer to. So you must indeed have a response first before you can even call `resp.raise_for_status()` (which throws an exception when the inspected [HTTP status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) is above 399).

Answer (score 9):

Much simpler check would be

```
    if resp.ok :
        print ('OK!')
    else:
        print ('Boo!')
```

Comment: This does not check for 200 OK only.

Comment: @colidyre is correct. Look at the docs: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.ok

Answer (score 8):

Since any 2XX class response is considered [successful](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3) in HTTP, I would use:

```
if 200 <= resp.status_code <= 299:
    print ('OK!') 
else:
    print ('Boo!')
```

Comment: `if resp.ok` has the same effect.

Comment: i wouldn't say same effect since it includes 3xx

Comment: * if 200 <= resp.status_code <= 299

Comment: This doesn't answer the question for `200 OK` specifically.

Answer (score 5):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned this. So:

### 1. Check for HTTP 200 OK

If you want to check for **exactly a 200 response**, use:

```py
if resp.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    ...
```

The [`status_code` of a response](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.status_code) contains the HTTP status returned.

`requests.codes.ok` is exactly 200.

---

### 2. Check if Response is not an Error

If you want to check if the status code is "ok", and **not an error**, use:

```
if resp.ok:
    ...
```

The [`ok` attribute of a response](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.ok) checks that the `status code` of the response is less than 400.

The [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.ok) even clarifies:

> "This is not a check to see if the response code is 200 OK."

---

Make sure you know what it is you want to check, for example a 201 HTTP Created is a successful response that you would be omitting if you only check for *exactly 200*.

Comment:  This is the most correct answer to the original question and should be way up there.

Answer (score 2):

`resp.status_code` will return the status code as an integer.

See http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
if resp.status_code == 200:
    print ('OK!')
else:
    print ('Boo!)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also the `http.HTTPStatus` in [`http` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.html#http.HTTPStatus), for better readability.

```py
from http import HTTPStatus

if resp.status_code == HTTPStatus.OK:
    print ('OK!')
else:
    print ('Boo!')
```

Comment: ⬆️ I like that you've used a **constant** and used one from the **standard library** although [Requests provides a similar interface](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#status-code-lookup).

Answer (score -1):

In easy case:

```
import requests

response = requests.get(url)
if not response:
    #handle error here
else:
    #handle normal response
```