# Flutter/Dart: Easy way to check if http request was successful?

Tags: flutter, dart

While using Flutters `http` request library I was wondering if there was an easy way to check **if a request was successful without having to check the status code**.

Most code samples I saw ([including official ones](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#convert-the-httpresponse-to-an-album)) do something like this:

```dart
http.Response response = await http.Client().get(...);
    
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   ...
}
```

However, those examples are ignoring the fact that all HTTP status codes starting with `2XX` are considered successful. For example `201` stands for `201 Created`.

I know for a fact that pythons `http` library has a simple `ok` flag, so in python could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087303/python-requests-how-to-check-for-200-ok):

```py
if response.ok:
   ...
```

Is there a feature like this in flutter/dart or do I have to implement a manual check?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can make an [extension method](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods) that does this easily:

```dart
extension IsOk on http.Response {
  bool get ok {
    return (statusCode ~/ 100) == 2;
  }
}
```

By adding the extension above, you can use the same response `response.ok` syntax that you like.

---

This extension works by isolating the 100th place digit by doing a [truncating division](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/num/operator_truncate_divide.html) by 100 and comparing the result to 2.

Comment: Wow thats great I was not aware of the fact that dart has such a cool feature.

Comment: cool stuff, works great

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check if an HTTP request was successful in Flutter/Dart using the [`http_status` package](https://pub.dev/packages/http_status). Here's how you can do it:

1. Classic method

   ```dart
   import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
   import 'package:http_status/http_status.dart';

   final res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

   if (res.statusCode == HttpStatusCode.ok) { // res.statusCode == 200
     final httpStatus = HttpStatus.fromCode(res.statusCode);

     return {
       'statusCode': res.statusCode,
       'httpStatus': httpStatus,
       'data': res.body
     };
   }
   ```
2. Alternative method (Same as #1 method, but with more direct validation using `.isSuccessfulHttpStatusCode`)

   ```dart
   import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
   import 'package:http_status/http_status.dart';

   final res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

   if (res.statusCode.isSuccessfulHttpStatusCode) { // Http Status Code 200 - 299
     final httpStatus = HttpStatus.fromCode(res.statusCode);

     return {
       'statusCode': res.statusCode,
       'httpStatus': httpStatus,
       'data': res.body
     };
   }
   ```
3. Alternative method (Same as #1 method, if you need the HttpStatus object from the dynamically generated status code of the response)

   ```dart
   import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
   import 'package:http_status/http_status.dart';

   final res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

   final httpStatusResponse = HttpStatus.fromCode(res.statusCode);

   if (httpStatusResponse.isSuccessfulHttpStatusCode) { // Http Status Code 200 - 299
     return {
       'statusCode': res.statusCode,
       'httpStatus': httpStatusResponse,
       'data': res.body
     };
   } else if (httpStatusResponse.isClientErrorHttpStatusCode) { // Http Status Code 400 - 499
      // Handle client error
      // ...
   } else {
      // Handle other code error
      // ...
   }
   ```