# JSon()[list] returns error :"keyerror list"

Tags: python

```
import requests

API_KEY = "your_api_key"
SEARCH_ENGINE_ID = "Your_search_engine_id"
QUERY = "kaytontukihenkilo"

url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={API_KEY}&cx={SEARCH_ENGINE_ID}&q={QUERY}&cr=countryFI"

response = requests.get(url)
results = response.json()["list"]

for result in results:
    print(result["title"])
    print(result["link"])
    print(result["snippet"])
    print()
```

I tried to run the code to get a list of available work in google, with a keyword, from finland,    but seeing: keyerror "list" what could be wrong?

Comment: There's no `list` key in the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/Search) I think you want `items`.

Comment: nope, same error this time error is the key items, it should get information from an google api,  if i remember correctly, but somehow doesnt work.

Comment: Have you tried using `print(results)` to see what the actual keys are?

Comment: The information strored in the api is named with a keyword, and this should be it, but doesnt work...

Comment: Did you read the documentation I linked to? It shows the keys of the search response.

Comment: not quite sure how to do that since the program stops to the "wrong" keyword so that the results dont generate.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say `print(response.json())`

Comment: I added print(response.json()) and it seems i dont have the credentials needed to make the search. Thats where i am now. Still if this isnt the case , any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you replace `your_api_key` and `Your_search_engine_id` with your actual key and ID?

Comment: yes i did.and activated the keys and everything

Comment: Add the response JSON to the question if you want help resolving it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python requests: how to check for "200 OK"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087303/python-requests-how-to-check-for-200-ok)

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting an error in the response. You should check the response code to know if the result will contain a list or an error.

Print the json result or/and do some testing in the [developers api page](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/cse/list?apix=true&hl=es-419).

[image]

Double-check your [imput parameters](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/Search?hl=en).

Check the response json structure. The json field with the results is a list, but it will only present if no errors arrise.